# Search anywhere in a filename for a string, case insensitive. Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Env: Python 3.6,  O/S: Windows 10

I have the following code that will search for filenames that contain a string either at the start (`.startswith`) of a filename or the end of a filename (`.endswith`), including sub directories and is case sensitive, i.e. `searchText = 'guess'` as opposed to `searchText = 'Guess'`.

I would like to modify`if FILE.startswith(searchText):` that allows a search anywhere in the filename and is case insensitive.  Is this possible?

For example, a directory contains two files called `GuessMyNumber.py` and `guessTheNumber.py`.
I would like to search for `'my'` and the code to return the filename `GuessMyNumber.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

#  set text to search for 
searchText = 'Guess'

#   the root (top of tree hierarchy) to search, remember to change \ to / for Windows
TOP = 'C:/works'

found = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(TOP, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=True):

        for FILE in files:
            if FILE.startswith(searchText):
                print ("\nFile {} exists..... \t\t{}".format(FILE, os.path.join(root)))
                found += 1

            else:
                pass

print('\n File containing \'{}\' found {} times'.format(searchText, found))
```

Thanks guys,
Tommy.

Comment: You should use either `fnmatch` or `glob` standard modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `glob`-based approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import glob


#  set text to search for 
searchText = 'Guess'

#   the root (top of tree hierarchy) to search, remember to change \ to / for Windows
TOP = 'C:/works'

found = 0
for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(TOP, '**', f'*{searchText}*'), recursive=True):
    print ("\nFile {} exists..... \t\t{}".format(filename, os.path.dirname(filename)))
    found += 1


print('\n File containing \'{}\' found {} times'.format(searchText, found))
```

---

A simple `fnmatch`-based approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import fnmatch


#  set text to search for 
searchText = 'Guess'

#   the root (top of tree hierarchy) to search, remember to change \ to / for Windows
TOP = 'C:/works'

found = 0
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(TOP, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=True):
    for filename in filenames:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, f'*{searchText}*'):
            print ("\nFile {} exists..... \t\t{}".format(filename, os.path.join(root)))
            found += 1

print('\n File containing \'{}\' found {} times'.format(searchText, found))
```

---

You could also use a PERL-compatible (more general) regular expression supported by `re` instead of the POSIX-compatible (less general) supported by `glob` and `fnmatch`.
However, in this simple scenario, the POSIX-compatible is more than enough.

Comment: @ norok2  Thank you for the code and your answer,  it works quite well.  This code only returns a list files, no directories of the same name included in the list, excellent.  I would like to know what the "f" in the code f'*{searchText}*' means.  I have read through the docs and I cannot find a reference nor explanation.  Tommy.

Comment: Thank you once again norok2.  There is also a good guide to string interpolation on https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can locally store all the .py files in your directory with their absolute path, use a simple regex to see if the absolute path has "Guess" or "guess" (depends on your use). Try this code and let us know

```
import pathlib
import os
import re
required=[]
    for filepath in pathlib.Path('C:\\your\\directory').glob('**/*.py'): #any file extension
        required.append(os.path.abspath(filepath)      
nameregex=re.compile(r'(.*Guess)')
mo=list(filter(nameregex.match, required))
print(mo) 
#or len will give you the length of the list
print(len(mo))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and code Hari.  Unfortunately the code is returning the following error        
     File "findfile03c.py", line 9
     nameregex=re.compile(r'(.*Guess)')
            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tommy.

Comment: Try adding a .* after the Guess in the nameregex line like this,
nameregex=re.compile(r'(.*Guess.*)')